# How to show title attributes onfocus using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml, accessibility

By default in all browsers, title attributes only show on mouse over. I want to show on keyboard focus also. I know this is not possible through only HTML and CSS.

JavaScript will be needed. so i use jquery in almost all projects. so i need a jquery solution to show title on onfocus.

```
<a title="this is title" href="#">Websites</a>
```

**Later added:**

After searching a lot on google i found a javascript solution

Now i just need a jquery version of this

see here : http://www.brothercake.com/scripts/tooltips/tooltips.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JS code**

```
$(function() {
        var xOffset = 10;
        var yOffset = 20;

        $("input").focus(function(e) {
            this.t = this.title;
            this.title = "";
            $("body").append("<span id='tooltip'>" + this.t + "</span>");
            $("#tooltip").css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px").fadeIn("fast");
        });

        $("input").blur(function(e) {
            this.title = this.t;
            $("#tooltip").remove();

            $("#tooltip").css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");   
        });   
    });
```

**CSS**

```
 #tooltip{
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid #333;
  background:#f7f5d1;
  padding:2px 5px;
  color:#333;
  display:none;
  }
```

the HTML element

```
 <input title="testing the focus tooltip" name="name" type="text"/>
```

Just for the fun of coding here the same but for **A link** element

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  this.focus(function (e) {
      this.t = this.title;
      this.title = "";                    
    $("body").append("<span id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</span>");
    $("#tooltip")
      .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
      .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
      .fadeIn("fast");    
    });
});

 <a title="fdsfsdfsd" href="javascript:;" >test a foucs</a>
```

Comment: sorry, i have not read the added link, although, this is the easy way i know for make tooltip! and yes it's jquery! hope this help!

Comment: ah, anyway the method is almost the same, get position, catch the focus event, get title, append title to body, display it fancy, remove it, start again...! ;-)

Comment: will this code work without jquery library? or jquery not needed

Comment: this require jquery! :-( if you want "raw" JS tooltip in small code try this http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create_lightweight_javascript_tooltip/

Comment: i need onfcous , mouseover is default

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of plugins like [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) that will let you do this in a cross-browser fashion. I doubt that you can trigger the native tooltip reliably. qTip code is quite straightforward:

```
$('ul:last li.active').qtip({
   content: 'This is an active list element',
   show: 'mouseover',
   hide: 'mouseout'
})
```

I'm not sure if it supports multiple show events (in your case, mouseover and focus).

Comment: I don't want this type thing. i just want to show browser default mouseover tooltip on onfocus

Comment: @jitendra - I don't think that's possible. That's a function that's left up to individual browsers to implement, and is not something that's accessible via code I don't think sorry.

Comment: Well, no, it's not possible or at least the source you provide does not show it is. The script you provided the link for creates divs and handles them, but it does not trigger the browser-native tooltip mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the author of [Onfocus tooltips](http://www.brothercake.com/scripts/tooltips/tooltips.html) to use their code.

jQuery is not necessary because the code enables the tooltipping for all elements in the document.  You may need to modify the script yourself if you want to tooltip elements which are dynamically generated.